# difficulties with COUNT function

Tags: sql

I am new to SQL and am having trouble using the count function to determine how many 'YES' or 'NO' for each criteria - apologies, this may be a stupid question.

I have a table with data like this (there are more businesstravel categories):

| attrition | businesstravel |
| --- | --- |
| Yes | Travel_Rarely |
| No | Travel_Frequently |
| Yes | Travel_Rarely |
| No | Travel_Frequently |
| No | Travel_Rarely |

And I want to count how many 'Yes' and 'No's align to each of the businesstravel categories. For example, like the below:

| attrition | businesstravel | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Yes | Travel_Rarely | 43 |
| No | Travel_Rarely | 65 |
| Yes | Travel_Frequently | 72 |
| No | Travel_Frequently | 5 |

I have tried the below but no luck:

- SELECT businesstravel, attrition
- COUNT(attrition)
- FROM wa_fn_usec_hr_employee_attrition_tsv
- GROUP BY businesstravel;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is nearly right.
You're missing a comma after "attrition" and you need to add attrition in the group by.

> ```
> create table 
> wa_fn_usec_hr_employee_attrition_tsv(
> attrition varchar(10),
> businesstravel varchar(50));
> insert into 
> wa_fn_usec_hr_employee_attrition_tsv
> values
> ('Yes','Travel_Rarely'),
> ('No','Travel_Frequently'),
> ('Yes','Travel_Rarely'),
> ('No','Travel_Frequently'),
> ('No','Travel_Rarely');
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
>   businesstravel, 
>   attrition,
>   COUNT(*)
> FROM wa_fn_usec_hr_employee_attrition_tsv
> GROUP BY 
>   businesstravel,
>   attrition;
> ```
>
> ```
> businesstravel    | attrition | COUNT(*)
> :---------------- | :-------- | -------:
> Travel_Rarely     | Yes       |        2
> Travel_Frequently | No        |        2
> Travel_Rarely     | No        |        1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b96a31376dfa0739a1b508139f559376)*

Comment: When I then go to 'ORDER by count ASC;' it comes up with '(' expected but keyword 'ORDER' found (line 9, column 1)
ORDER by count ASC;
^
Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT C.attrition, C.businesstravel,COUNT(*)CNTT
FROM YOUR_TABLE   C
GROUP BY C.attrition, C.businesstravel
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to group by attrition and businesstravel because count of these unique group is required. Hope below query helps:-

```
select attrition,businesstravel,count(attrition)  from biz
   group by attrition,businesstravel
```